# How to handle config changes in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, savestate

I have simple registration form. When I enter data and change configuration the data is lost. I use ViewModel in my project and official documentation says ViewModel can handle orientation change automatically but it does not happen. How i suppose to store data with SaveState or I made a mistake in ViewModel?

[image: my registration form]

Fragment code

```
class StartFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: StartFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.start_fragment, container, false)
        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

        val dataSource = UsersDatabase.getInstance(application).usersDatabaseDao
        val vm: SavedStateHandle by viewModels()
        val viewModelFactory = StartFragmentViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)

        val startFragmentViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(
                this, viewModelFactory).get(StartFragmentViewModel::class.java)

        binding.startFragmentViewModel = startFragmentViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.start.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(
                    StartFragmentDirections
                        .actionStartFragmentToWebViewFragment())
                startFragmentViewModel.doneNavigation()
            }
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class StartFragmentViewModel(
    val database: UsersDatabaseDao,
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var viewModelJob = Job()

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }

    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)
    private var user1 = MutableLiveData<User?>()


    private val _navigateToWebView = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val navigateToWebView: LiveData<User>
        get() = _navigateToWebView

    fun doneNavigation() {
        _navigateToWebView.value = null
        uiScope.launch {
            val user = User()
            insert(user)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun insert(user: User) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            database.insert(user)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelFactory

```
class StartFragmentViewModelFactory (
    private val dataSource: UsersDatabaseDao,
    private val application: Application
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(StartFragmentViewModel::class.java)) {
                return StartFragmentViewModel(dataSource, application) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
        }
}
```

[image]

start_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="startFragmentViewModel"
            type="com.example.leadsdoittest.StartFragmentViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/margin_start"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/margin_end"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/margin_top"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_name"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/margin_end"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/margin_start"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/margin_top">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/name" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_phone"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/margin_end"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/margin_start"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:hint="@string/phone_number" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_email"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/margin_end"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/margin_start"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_phone">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/margin_end"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/margin_start"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_email" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View state is handled by the framework so you don't need to implement it yourself. However the saved state depends on having unique IDs on each view, so try adding an ID to each `TextInputEditText`.

Comment: It worked! You've saved me a tonn of time. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Use instance variable to restore data after rotation. Look:

```
   class StartFragment  : Fragment() {

    //private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    var name = ""
    var email = ""
    var phone = ""
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater)

        binding.etName.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
            name = text.toString()
        }
        binding.etPhone.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
            phone = text.toString()
        }
        binding.etEmail.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
            email = text.toString()
        }
        binding.etName.setText(name)
        binding.etEmail.setText(email)
        binding.etPhone.setText(phone)
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: So i need onCreate() and onCreateView()? And if i use both how to initialize binding.startFragmentViewModel? Because startFragmentViewModel initialized in onCreate?

Comment: Added screenshot to visulize what i mean.

Comment: Are you using multiple view model ? Are you using dynamic data binding ?

Comment: I only have one ViewModel for the fragment. What do you mean dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic data binding, its not a new concept. You might have heard. Okay, Tell me one thing ui data is refreshed or view model data is refreshed after rotation ?

Comment: I need to save enetered but not saved data. So i suppose it's ui data

Comment: Why are you inserting empty user to data base ? Look at :  fun doneNavigation() {
        _navigateToWebView.value = null
        uiScope.launch {
            val user = User()
            insert(user)
        }
    }

Comment: can I see your xml file where you actually binding view model ?

Comment: It's the next bug I wanted to fix. Thank you, i don't want to insert empty user

Comment: Added xml file in post

Comment: I updated answer. By using instance variable data is showing perfectly. Check my answer. I am using TextInputEditText 's id , not id of TextInputLayout

Comment: So the best option in this case is to use savedInstanseState?

Comment: Yeah, thanks. savedInstanceState works as expected.